# Como fazer consulta em um select que tenha dois valores?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um campo que digito o código referente e ele já seleciona automático o select para facilitar a vida do usuário que já sabe os código.

Tenho esse select com dois valores em uma lista. Gostaria de saber como eu posso fazer uma busca no select cuja o valor de pesquisa está na posição 1.

```js
$('#inputTurno2').change(function () {
  var valSelecionado = $(this).val();
  var turno = JSON.parse(valSelecionado);
  $('#iputTurno1').val(turno[1])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="form-control pular_inclusa" id="iputTurno1" placeholder="cod">
<select name="turno" class="form-control" id="inputTurno2">
  <option value="['', '']">---------</option>
  <option value="[1, 1]">Alvorada</option>
  <option value="[10, 2]">Federal</option>
</select>
```

O contrario eu consigo, selecionar algum valor no select e ele colocar o valor que preciso no input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale lembrar que o parse de `"['', '']"` pode ser problemático e que `codigo` inicialmente será `string`. 
Aqui tem a documentação [$().each](https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function)

```
$('#iputTurno1').blur(function () {
  var codigo = Number($(this).val());
  $("#inputTurno2 option").each(function () {
    var rawValues = $(this).val();
    var values = JSON.parse(rawValues);
    if (values && values[1] == codigo) {
        $('#inputTurno2').val(rawValues);
        // aqui ja encontramos a única opção então vamos parar o $().each
        return false
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Pois é eu mudei o parse para [0,0], e com isso funcionou.
com alguns acréscimo e ajuste que você propôs no código eu consegui resolver outra parte que não estava conseguindo tratar, que foi colocar um alert para falar que não existe o código digitado. 

Muito obrigado pela ajuda, tenho pouco tempo que iniciei no java script ainda aprendendo.

Answer (score 0):

Conseguir resolver fazend

```js
$('#iputTurno1').blur(function () {
            var codigo = $(this).val();
            $("#inputTurno2 option").each(function () {
                var valores = $(this).val();
                var teste = JSON.parse(valores);
                if(teste[1] == codigo){
                    $('#inputTurno2').val(valores);
                }
            });
```

o esse código via jquery.